# Labeling distance between points on python plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, euclidean-distance

I have a list of points listed in pts.along with the lines connecting these points to make a tetrahedron.  I am trying to find a way to add labels showing the euclidean distance between each point.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Plot points
pts = [(a,0,0),(b,0,0),(c1,c2,0),(z1,z2,z3)]
for p in pts:
    ax.scatter(p[0], p[1], p[2], zdir='z', c='r')

# Plot tetrahedron
for a, b in itertools.product(pts, pts):
    x = np.linspace(a[0], b[0], 100)
    y = np.linspace(a[1], b[1], 100)
    z = np.linspace(a[2], b[2], 100)
    ax.plot(x, y, z)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What problem are you having? What is the question?  Maybe look through the [Matplotlib Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/gallery/index.html#text-labels-and-annotations) to see if there are examples with features you want and then adapt the example(s) to your needs.  Or maybe spend some time with [the Annotation Tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could calculate the distances and then use `text` to display them.

Here they land right on the line, but with the 3D plot and projections, it would be difficult to automatically put them in a better place.  Note also that using `product` makes duplicate points, so I only show distance with `d>0`.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import itertools
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Plot points
a, b, c1, c2, z1, z2, z3 = 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 3
pts = [(a,0,0),(b,0,0),(c1,c2,0),(z1,z2,z3)]
for p in pts:
    ax.scatter(p[0], p[1], p[2], zdir='z', c='r')

# Plot tetrahedron
for a, b in itertools.product(pts, pts):
    x = np.linspace(a[0], b[0], 100)
    y = np.linspace(a[1], b[1], 100)
    z = np.linspace(a[2], b[2], 100)
    d = np.sqrt( sum([(a[i]-b[i])**2 for i in (0, 1, 2)]) )
    s = "%.2f" % d
    m = [(a[i]+b[i])/2. for i in (0, 1, 2)]
    ax.plot(x, y, z)
    if d>0:
        ax.text(m[0], m[1], m[2], s)
    print a, b, s

plt.show()
```